# Can we define integration of a function with respect to any $2$-tensor field?

Tags: integration, differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, differential-forms

Suppose $M$ is a smooth manifold and $g$ be any continuous $2$-tensor field. Then we define the integration of any compactly supported continuous function on $M$ as the following.

If $\text{supp}f\subseteq U$ where $(U,\phi)$ is a smooth chart, define $\int_Mf:=\int_{\phi(U)}f\circ\phi^{-1}\sqrt{|\text{det}(g_{ij})|}dx_1\dots dx_n $ where $g_{ij}:=g(\partial/\partial x_i,\partial/\partial x_i)$. One can see that this definition is independent of the chosen smooth chart. Now for general compactly supported function we can define the integration using partition of unity.

Is the above mentioned construction alright? In literature, I have seen the above mentioned construction when $g$ is a non-degenerate symmetric $2$-tensor field. Why one insists $g$ to be symmetric and non-degenerate, when we can define the integration with respect to any $2$-tensor field?

Comment: Think of $\sqrt{|det(g_{ij})|}dx_{1}...dx_{n}$ as a volume measure on $M$. Using the fact that the standard basis on $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ is orthonormal, you can verify the determinant of $n$ vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ measures the volume of the simplex spanned by these vectors (up to a sign), so a nondegenerate symmetric 2-tensor field (=pseudo-riemannian metric, if it is also positive definite it is called a riemannian metric) on $M$ kinda allows you to do the same thing - but we want $g$ to have at least some of the properties of an inner product, for geometric reasons.

Comment: It appears in other cases as well: Up to a constant factor, the above construction also gives the standard volume form on a symplectic manifold, though it is seldom written that way.

Comment: If $g$ is degenerate, then the above construction will lead to a vanishing determinant, thus a null-measure, that is not that interesting.